# Woocommerce 3.7: Set Product to Out of Stock but it doesn't show in report

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I set a product to out of stock (OOS) programatically below, it appears fine on Woocommerce>Products and on the front end, however it doesn't show up on the report  `Woocommerce>Reports>Stock>Out of Stock`

However, If I edit a product manually and set its stock status to out of stock and check the Manage Stock box, the product will display in the above OOS report.

// Update stock status

```
update_post_meta($product_id, '_stock_status', 'outofstock');
```

// Update manage stock

```
update_post_meta($product_id, '_manage_stock', yes);
```

// Update stock quantity

```
update_post_meta($product_id, '_stock', 0);
```

// Update post term relationship

```
wp_set_post_terms($product_id, 'outofstock', 'product_visibility', true);
```

Any idea how to get it to show on the report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do your modifications as follows -

```
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    // Update stock status
    $product->set_stock_status('outofstock');
    // Update manage stock
    $product->set_manage_stock('yes');
    // Update stock quantity
    $product->set_stock_quantity(0);
    // Update post term relationship
    $product->set_catalog_visibility('hidden');

    // Save the data and refresh caches
    $product->save();
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to writing WC plugins. When I insert your code into my plugin I get the WP white screen of death. Do I need to include a WC 3 class library in my code?

Comment: Can you tell me in which hook/filter you are using to do your changes or writen the above codes.

Comment: Here is my plugin:

Comment: <?php
/**
* Plugin Name: WC 3 OOS Control
* Plugin URI: https://www.example.com/
* Description: 
* Version: 1.0
* Author: 
* Author URI: 
**/

$product_id = 14106;

$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
     // Update stock status
     $product->set_stock_status('outofstock');
     // Update manage stock
     $product->set_manage_stock('yes');
     // Update stock quantity
     $product->set_stock_quantity(0);
     // Update post term relationship
     $product->set_catalog_visibility('hidden');
     // Save the data and refresh caches
     $product->save();
?>

Comment: I'm running the plugin from the command line. I'm planning to use this plugin as a cron job.

Comment: You are doing it a wrong way. Try to do your changes using `save_post_product` hook. Or if for for cronjob try to fetch first all your specific products, then within every product loop  you can add above code to change stock. But before it I must say please go through the hook filter or cron job documentations for WordPress codex

Comment: Thanks, I will research that. However I'm confused. Why does my original code using update_post_meta & wp_set_post_terms work fine (except for the oos report) but when using your code, wp shows the white screen of death?

Comment: Here is the error thrown by wp debug: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wc_get_product()

Comment: Your functionalities are calling before WC initialised, that's why you are getting this error. Please paste your full codes in your above question.